# Is there any standard graph data structure available for benchmark?

Tags: c++, graph, standards, benchmarking

I am trying to perform some benchmarks in some graph data structures in C++ - my goal is to optimize data layouts.

Since data layouts are important to my context, I was wondering if there is any pre-defined standard graph structure, commonly used for graph benchmarks - i.e., a standard graph **form** used to strain memory systems. Has someone ever bumped into something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the Boost implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html